# How to read this Microcontroller table?

Tags: microcontroller, freescale

I am a beginner in Microcontroller electronics.

[MPC5606S MCU Datasheet](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/MPC5606S.pdf)

I want to understand how to read the table 8 - Port Pin Summary. Can you please explain clearly the each word present in the function and peripherals column? Ex. eMIOSA, SOUND, SIUL, DCU etc. What is the purpose? Please.

And Some ports have 5V input and some ports have 3.3V input. Where to find this information in the attached datasheet? I think table 5 gives the Voltage for the input ports. For output ports, how do we understand which pin/port gives which voltage i.e. 5V or 3.3V?

Thanks.

Comment: each pin has different functions available ..... the function is selected by the program ...... perhaps exploring a simpler device will clear up some of your questions ..... maybe have a look at this http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-2586-AVR-8-bit-Microcontroller-ATtiny25-ATtiny45-ATtiny85_Datasheet.pdf

Comment: These will of course be defined elsewhere in the document.  PDF viewers have as search function...

Comment: Thank you. I will read that. Is there any course where I can learn Microcontrollers (Hardware and Software combined) from the scratch? I tried in Udemy / Coursera and Udacity but I could not find any course related to MCU Hardware. Only MCU courses related to programming are given

Comment: If you are really new to microcontrollers and have such difficulties with reading this datasheet/table, I think you should start with something easier, e.g. 8-bit AVR family (Arduino). It has much lower entry threshold and steep learning curve with very big community and a lot of software/hardware examples.

Comment: If you are a beginner and still want to achieve college-level expertise, you may be interested in  the lectures of professor Bruce Land at Cornell university. Just google for "bruce land microcontrollers" and you'll get a link to his home page. He put his lectures on youtobe (there are 3 recent semesters based on PIC32 architecture and an older one - 2012 - based on AVR 8 bit architecture).

Comment: If you are a beginner please note that the MPC56 family is very complex. Some ARM Cortex M would be much easier to start with. And please don't listen to people who tell you to study 8 bit MCUs from the previous millennium.

Comment: So for analogy, you want to get a driving license. MPC56 is pretty a formula 1 race car filled with lots of strange buttons and blinking lights, eager to crash into a wall at 300km/h. ARM Cortex-M is a functional Toyota. Arduino is a toy car saying "wrooom!". Pick the car you think would suit someone studying for a driving license.

Comment: @Lundin This is ridiculous, man can't figure out what pins are for and what voltage they are tolerant, and you say he should start with Cortex-M? Really? And why AVR are from previous millennium? The architecture was developed in 1996, but production was started in 2000s. Why don't you say don't start with ARM (1985) from previous millennium? Or don't use x86 (1976) computers from there? Try to program AVR without Arduino IDE in C/C++ with you own peripheral drivers. Also reading and understanding its datasheet is much more easy, typically its 150-200 pages in total, not about 2000 for Cortex.

Comment: @cyclone125 I say this because I have programmed 8 bit MCUs for the past 15 years and therefore know exactly how bad they are. Memory banking. 32 bit arithmetic through software libs. Non-existent stack depth. C language implicit promotion nightmares. Non-existent code efficiency wasting speed, flash and current consumption. And for AVR you also have the Harvard problem on top of all the other crap. ARM is like a breeze compared to all of that.

Comment: @Lundin Not to mention that fact, that modern 8-bit MCU can easily handle 90+% of tasks where typically MCUs are used, (if you don't convert video or have realtime 3D graphics or something similar). So AVR is not "toy car", nor Arduino is. Better to say that Arduino is self-driving car, while AVR is the car where you should drive yourself.

Comment: @cyclone125 Yeah sure you can program all manner of complex applications with 8 bitters. Hard real-time systems, DSP-like radio decoding, PID controllers... done all that, it's a form of self-torture and belongs to the past. I wouldn't pick a 8 bit MCU for a new project even if you pay me to use it.

Comment: @Lundin So you had easy start in MCU, and after 12 years of learning you advice someone else to start from the point where you are now, right?

Comment: Thank you all. The problem is that, I require some teacher/mentor who can guide me and help me if I have any doubts. Self-reading is helping. But while doing so, I have soo many doubts where I get stuck. I dont think coming to this forum to post all simple doubts (for your standards) will help in the long run. That's why you get these type of questions. Thank you for the info on lectures of Prof. Land and the analogy. Please provide more inputs on lectures or easy study material. Thank you all

Comment: Another thing is that, since my native language is not english, I'm finding hard to understand concepts and your explanations unless it is very basic. Anyway, I will try my best. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is a picture of the last page of the VERY long Table 8.  I purposely put in the last page because it contains all of the notes, which are very important in a table like this.  The notes are indicated by the small number superscripts on some of the columns.  They add extra information and perhaps caveats to help with the design.

To answer your question, this table is presenting all of the possible connections for the I/O pins on the chip.  The connections are configured by writing registers internal to the chip.

The document you referenced is the datasheet for the chip.  For microprocessor chips, in addition to the data sheet, there is usually a reference manual.  The reference manual gives a full description of all of the internal registers and peripherals on the chip.  [This is the reference manual for the MPC5606S chip](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/reference-manual/MPC5606SRM.pdf) . In a concise 1344 pages, it provides all of the information you need to understand the names and abbreviations in the Table 8.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Most of these terms are Freescale/NXP internal gibberish terms that nobody understands, beginner or veteran. Page 6 in the datasheet you linked gives a helpful overview.

Of the terms used for peripherals in table 8, an engineer is supposed to recognize PWM, I2C, CAN, LIN, ADC, SPI, JTAG, LCD. The rest are internal names used by Freescale.

"SIUL" for example is their "System Integration Unit Lite", which is a fancy nonsense name for the general-purpose I/O hardware. Nexus is their debug interface compatible with JTAG. "DCU" is an unhelpful 3-letter abbreviation for display controller hardware. And so on.

Please note that what you have here is the "datasheet". It is what they toss to the EE who cad the PCB, but otherwise shouldn't worry about MCU internals. All the dirty details are found in the corresponding "user manual", which is a 1500-something pages document.

To know which pins/peripherals that can handle which voltages, you should check electrical characteristics.